# Como posso atualizar um JLabel?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jframe

Preciso atualizar um JLabel toda vez que aperto um determinado botão que busca um formulário do banco de dados para gerar um gráfico, mas isso funciona apenas na primeira vez.
A minha ideia foi a seguinte: caso o JLabel esteja vazio ele adiciona o gráfico gerado pela busca, caso esteja preenchido ele removeria o gráfico e colocaria o novo.
Desse modo meu JFrame ficou assim:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblMeuIcone = new JLabel("");
        lblMeuIcone.setBounds(23, 11, 363, 205);
        contentPane.add(lblMeuIcone);

        JButton btnTrocarI = new JButton("TrocarImagem");
        btnTrocarI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                GeradorDeGraficos graficos = new GeradorDeGraficos();
                int[] valores = {1,1,2,23,3};
                graficos.graficoPeriodoDeCrescimento(valores, "grafico 01", "valores", "valores");
                try {
                    graficos.salvarGrafico(new FileOutputStream("MyChart01.png"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(lblMeuIcone.getIcon() == null) {
                    File file = new File("MyChart01.png");
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    lblMeuIcone.setIcon(icon);
                    }else {
                        lblMeuIcone.setIcon(null);
                        File file = new File("MyChart01.png");
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        lblMeuIcone.setIcon(icon);
                    }
            }
        });
        btnTrocarI.setBounds(70, 227, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnTrocarI);

        JButton btnTrocarII = new JButton("Trocar nova");
        btnTrocarII.setBounds(311, 227, 89, 23);
        btnTrocarII.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                GeradorDeGraficos graficos = new GeradorDeGraficos();
                int[] valores = {10,5,6,23,33};
                graficos.graficoPeriodoDeCrescimento(valores, "grafico 02", "valores", "valores");
                try {
                    graficos.salvarGrafico(new FileOutputStream("MyChart01.png"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(lblMeuIcone.getIcon() == null) {
                File file = new File("MyChart01.png");
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
                lblMeuIcone.setIcon(icon);
                }else {
                    lblMeuIcone.setIcon(null);
                    File file = new File("MyChart01.png");
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    lblMeuIcone.setIcon(icon);
                }
                }

        });
        contentPane.add(btnTrocarII);
    }

}
```

Classe que gera o gráfico

```
public class GeradorDeGraficos {
    private double[] valores;
    private int inicio;
    private int fim;

    float dash[] = { 10.f };

    private DefaultCategoryDataset data;
    private JFreeChart grafico;
    private JFreeChart graficoDeLinha;

    public JFreeChart graficoPeriodoDeCrescimento(int[] lista, String titulo, String labelBottom, String labelLeft) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
                dataset.addValue(lista[i], "Média", "valor" + i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "deu pau no grafico");
        }

        graficoDeLinha = ChartFactory.createLineChart(titulo, labelBottom, labelLeft, dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        // fonte
        Font fonteNova = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 18);

        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = graficoDeLinha.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();

        CategoryPlot plot = graficoDeLinha.getCategoryPlot();

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GREEN);
        plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(12.0, 12.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.RED);
        // cor e linha das séries
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0,
                new BasicStroke(1.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.f, dash, 0.0f));
        renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,
                new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER));
        renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0,
                new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.f, dash, 0.0f));
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.GREEN);

        // legendas
        LegendItemCollection legendas = new LegendItemCollection();
        LegendItem legenda1 = new LegendItem("Crescimento");
        legenda1.setSeriesIndex(0);
        legenda1.setFillPaint(Color.BLUE);
        legenda1.setLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
        legenda1.setLabelFont(fonteNova);
        legendas.add(legenda1);

        plot.setFixedLegendItems(legendas);

        return graficoDeLinha;

    }

    public void salvarGrafico(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, graficoDeLinha, 300, 200);
    }

}
```

qualquer duvida é só falar

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: O problema é que seu codigo nao é reproduzivel por conter banco de dados. Pode isolar o problema apenas no botao e no label citado com alguns dados direto no codigo? Remova tudo q nao for necessario, deixando apenas o suficiente pra simular seu problema.

Comment: Esse código é seu?

Comment: Adiciona os imports tambem, está dando erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela documentação do `ImageIcon`, o construtor usado no código - `ImageIcon(String)` - usa um `MediaTracker` para carregar a imagem. O `MeidaTracker salva a imagem num cache e usa essa iamgem em vez de ler novamente do (mesmo) arquivo - como o nome da arquivo não mudou, é assumido que a imagem não foi alterada.

Solução: use o `ImageIO` para ler a imagem e o construtor `ImageIcon(Image)`:

```
// gerar gráfico e salvar em 'file'

BufferedImage img;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
label.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem, obrigado